# How can i disable infowindow for origin and destination on Google map?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating direction service on google map. Everything is working fine. 
I want to disable infowindow of origin(A) and destination(B) points only not marker's. How can I hide it or remove it?

[Check this attached image for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FYWO.png)

[image]

Here is code for setup google map. It is written in angular.

```
$scope.directionsService.route({
    origin: {'placeId': $scope.originPlaceId},
    destination: {'placeId': $scope.destinationPlaceId},
    travelMode: defaultTravelMode
},
function (response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
        $scope.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        $scope.path = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: response.routes[0].overview_path
        });
        // filter stores by path
        $scope.filterStoresByDirectionPath($scope.path);
    }
});

//function to design infowindow of marker

$scope.newMarker = function (opts) {
let marker = new google.maps.Marker(opts);
marker.travelTime = opts.travelTime;
marker.timeValue = opts.timeValue;
marker.url = opts.url;
$scope._on({
    obj: marker,
    event: 'click',
    callback: function () {
        let content = 'Marker content';

        if ($scope.infoWindow) {
            $scope.infoWindow.close();
        }


        $scope.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content});
        $scope.infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);

    }
});
```

Comment: Show your code that you have done yet

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please rewrite you question and include all relevant code so that people who are willing to help you, actually can.

Comment: @Ibnelaiq Please check I have updated my question